# RecyclerView and ViewHolder pattern - proper design approach

Tags: android, design-patterns, optimization, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I've got RecyclerView list where items views are created partially from layout in .xml file (let's say header) and partially programmatically based on list items. I'm using few different itemsViewTypes.

Which approach is better?

1) to generate Views in adapter:

```
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_item, parent, false);
    MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(view);
    createAndAddNewViews(barsHolder);
    createAndAddNewViewsBasedOnSomeParams(param1, param2);

    // both createAndAddNewViews() and   
    // createAndAddNewViewsBasedOnSomeParams() are Adapter methods

    return holder;
}
```

2) to generate Views in ViewHolder:

```
public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);

    ... // findViewsById and so on

    createAndAddNewViews();
    createAndAddNewViewsBasedOnSomeParams(param1, param2);

    // both createAndAddNewViews() and   
    // createAndAddNewViewsBasedOnSomeParams() are ViewHolder methods
}
```

Of course my examples are simplified just to show the case.

From code reading perspective it's better to have views generation logic inside holders. Every different item has it's own creation code inside one class. I don't have to deal with every single item in Adapter. But I'm not sure if it's ok simply from ViewHolder pattern design and from memory and speed optimization perspective.

I wonder which approach you consider as better and why.

Edit: Does the same applies for modifying view (onBindViewHolder) and methods in Adapter/ViewHolder?

Thanks!

Comment: Your `Adapter` should generate views using the `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` as it's ViewHolder class. So, it's a mixture of both of your proposals.

Comment: Can you ellaborate or show how that mix should looks like?

Based on: http://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html
"Root view" is inflated during onCreateViewHolder() method.

Comment: if your `MyViewHolder` class is changed to `extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder` then it's a mix of both; and instead of simply creating your `ViewHolder` like you did in your simplified case, you would create and bind it in `onCreateViewHolder()` and `onBindViewHolder()` respectivelly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Performance wise it's the same in both the approaches. If you have different ViewHolders for different itemTypes you can do in in ViewHolder to segregate the code belonging to a certain ViewHolder at one place